# Java - run a python code from shared memory

Tags: python, java, windows, ipc, shared-memory

When I use shared memory, I can ask the OS memory which is allowed to execute.
Is it possible to write to the memory the executable code in python (from a python process) and then execute it from a Java process?

I have a Java process that receives some data from a remote server, and another process in Python that knows how to process that data. After the Java process receives the data, it needs the processed data back. So Instead of sending the data to the python process and then get it back, I thought maybe the python process can share its processing code and the Java process will just use it. This way there's no need to lock the memory while writing.

Comment: Theoretically this is possible but starting a new separate Python process is much simpler and safer.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I edited the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: How is this even theoretically possible? Java will be running in a JVM and its structures will be unintelligible to Python, surely?

Comment: Won't you like to use named pipes, for example? Then no lock is required too and you just have two separate processes that can communicate fast and efficient.

Comment: In any case, this is really misguided. There is nothing to be gained here in efficiency; anything that makes this kind of shared memory work (I'm not convinced it can even get there) will be massive overhead

Comment: @SUTerliakov I'll try to use shared memory, it's much faster. We need to handle a lot of messages in a second. I thought maybe Java supports a way to execute python code, so maybe that would have been even faster. With shared memory, I do need to see how I lock the memory while writing.

Comment: But they're different processes, so they'll be allocated memory by the OS in separate blocks. I don't understand how this should be interchangeable between processes (which is what you're asking)

Comment: @roganjosh Only data of a specially prepared structure in a byte buffer can be shared between the runtimes. The internal structures can't, of course. Both runtimes can run in the same process, e. g. by creating a Java native library which imports the Python runtime library and starts it.

Comment: @roganjosh But shared memory is just for that, getting a memory that multiple processes can access.

Comment: Do you have an example to show where this has been performed between Java and Python before?

Comment: Memory mapped files can be used to share the same data between processes. They are supported by Python and Java. For transfer of commands and synchronization an additional approach like already mentioned pipes or sockets is necessary.

Comment: @roganjosh You're asking about sharing memory for just data exchanging, or sharing executable code and execute it?

Comment: @MichaelButscher For synchronization I can use Mutex, Semaphore, or InterlockedExchange, am I wrong?

Comment: @RonyTesler whichever it is that you're asking about

Comment: I don't doubt I could be wrong on my assessment with this, but this question is so open-ended and nebulous that it just doesn't seem answerable. If you can give us a concrete example of what you want, that would at least be a start

Comment: @RonyTesler If you use special libraries which give you access to the synchronization primitives of the OS.

Comment: I don't know about the executable part, that's why I posted the question. I'm sure about just sharing data between two processes. I tried to edit the question so it will be clearer what I want to do - process J (Java) gets some string from a remote server, it needs to ask process P (python) to parse that data, and P needs to send back the parsed data to process J. process J get about 100 messages like this in a second.

Comment: @roganjosh In case you are replying to someone's comment, please prepend the usual @ and username before your comment.

Comment: @MichaelButscher how was my comment in any way ambiguous in who I was speaking to? I am well-versed in Stack Overflow.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the python process can share its processing code and the Java process will just use it"? Both the source and byte code of Java and Python are widely different, sharing them between the VMs will not allow the JVM to run the PVM program. Have you considered using Jython, which is a PVM implemented on top of the JVM, to literally run the Python program inside the Java program?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This is what I'm looking at now. They're not that clear about how to use it. I see it supports only python 2.7. I can just use an original python script and tell java to run it?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Would that work - Process J (java) asks a shared memory from the OS, then sets it to all zeroes. Then it writes the string message to the shared memory, with "---" appended and then a byte counter (starts from 0) (I know that "---" won't be a part of the message itself). P (python) reads the message (with no locking). If the message has "---0", it knows the message itself was written successfully by J, then it handles the message. Next time P reads the message, it checks if it has "---1" and so on. Please read my next comment as well.

Comment: @roganjosh Following my previous comment - I don't care for now if P didn't read message x before J wrote message x+1. Is it OK to assume that if P reads "---1", then all the previous bytes had already been written successfully? This is the code that writes the data to the shared memory, from Bits.java: unsafe.copyMemory(src, offset, null, dstAddr, size). And from Unsafe.class: public native void copyMemory(Object var1, long var2, Object var4, long var5, long var7); I can write the counter part also with this: from DirectByteBuffer.java: unsafe.putByte(ix(nextPutIndex()), ((x))), if it helps.

Comment: This would work but without synchronization the receiving part would have to read the shared memory again and again until it finds the proper end mark. I would really recommend to use e. g. a network socket to send a notification that the data is available and where it is in the shared memory. The receiver can then just wait for the notification.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'll start with Message Queues, it's faster than sockets. Any reason to prefer sockets? What I suggested maybe would be better for very high volumes, when it's important to save time on the communication itself, and also because of the high volume, the reader wouldn't wait too much, I mean it will be faster to wait that short time rather than using a lock.

Comment: My only reason is that accessing message queues of the OS needs appropriate libraries for Java and Python while network socket support is part of the standard libraries of both runtime environments.